# exponentiate a matrix

Tags: linear-transformations

If $AS=SA$ then $\exp(A+S)=\exp(A) exp(S)$, 
since $aI$ commutes with any matrix ( $a$ is just a number and $I$ is the identity )

Then, $$\exp(aI+M)=e^a \exp(M)$$

I tried to justify $$\exp(aI+M)=e^a e^M $$ 
by claiming that 
 $$\exp(aI+M)=\exp(aI)\exp(M)=(e^a I)\exp(M) = e^a exp(M)$$, but why $$e^a * I = e^a $$

Comment: Hint: What is $e^{-M}e^M$?

Comment: Please use Mathjax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$e^a I $ is in general not equal to $e^a$. Try it with $2 \times 2$ matrices and $a = 0$; on the left you have $1$ and on the right, you hve the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix.

But for a matrix $M$, it IS true that 
$$
e^a I M = e^a M
$$
because $IM = M$.